cppcheck does not detect memory leak if the pointer is passed to another function in the same file that doesn't free it
In the following code, s is allocated using calloc and is never freed. But cppcheck does not detect this memory leak if it is passed to f1. Based on the cppcheck documentation, I believe it assumes that f1 may be taking care of it.
void f1(const char *s)
{
    printf("f1");
}

int main()
{
    char *s = calloc(10, sizeof(char));
    f1(s); // memleak is reported only if this is commented out
    return 0;
}


I have tried with 2.7 and 2.14.2 with the same results.
$ cppcheck test.c 
Checking test.c ...
test.c:15:2: error: Memory leak: s [memleak]
 return 0;

I know we can use <leak-ignore /> on a function to explicitly tell cppcheck that it is not freed in that function, but the docs say "if cppcheck doesn't know what dostuff does". But in this case, cppcheck clearly knows what it does, the code is available. And it is not practical to add leak-ignore flags for every function that accepts a pointer.
So my question is, is there a way to override this behaviour? As long as a pointer is only passed around in the same file, and it doesn't call any library functions that doesn't have <noreturn> associated with it, I don't see why the tool cannot ignore it.
I found a similar question, but that hasn't been answered properly; the sole answer just says it works for them, but it doesn't work with the latest version of cppcheck.

manpage says '-D By default Cppcheck checks all configurations. Use -D to limit the checking. When -D is used the checking is limited to the given configuration. Example: -DDEBUG=1 -D__cplusplus
-U By default Cppcheck checks all configurations. Use '-U' to explicitly hide certain #ifdef  code paths from checking. Example: '-UDEBUG', Raise this with the dev . NB: latest documentation is https://cppcheck.sourceforge.io/manual.pdf (differs from your link !)

@ticktalk how is that supposed to solve the issue? Do you suggest the OP uses -DCALL_F1? Or -UCALL_F1? And why should this be needed here?

"Here is how I am invoking Cppcheck (v2.7) [...] but it doesn't work with the latest version of Cppcheck" What is the version you are using? The latest is 2.14.2.

@ticktalk I used -D and -U so that I can use the same code to demo both cases. The results are the same if I comment out the function f1and invoked cppcheck without any flags

@rzickler I guess I'm using the version that comes with Ubuntu 22.04. I'll try to install the latest version and post the results

@rzickler I tried with 2.13 and got the same results. I doubt it will change with 2.14

printf("%s\n", s); // use s to avoid unused warning is not benign.  For it to work, s must be non-NULL.  A better way to "avoid unused warning" is (void) s;.

Note that code is not preventing UB of printf("%s\n", s); when s == NULL (due to failed allocation). IMO, f1() better as { if (s) printf("%s\n", s); }.

@chux-ReinstateMonica that's not relevant to the question though, is it?

@Amarghosh It is possible that the error discussed may be influenced by the potential UB of printf("%s\n", s);.  { if (s) printf("%s\n", s); } prevents that UB.

The error is the same irrespective of this line. I will edit the question to simplify the code.
